# Linux Disk Usage and Disk Size don't agree [Fedora 11]

Tags: linux, hard-drive, disk-space, lvm, fedora-11

I'm having an issue on a Xen VM where (running as root) df and baobab agree that 94% of my disk is used (25G out of 28G), but du only counts a fraction of total disk utilization (3.3G).

The server has a simple LVM configuration: a 28G partition mounted to /. lvdisplay and vgdisplay both show that the entire volume is accounted for.

How am I missing almost 22G worth of space?

```
df Output
=========
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_dns-lv_root
                  29241444  25924244   1831788  94% /

df -h Output
============
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_dns-lv_root
                   28G   25G  1.8G  94% /

`du --max-depth=1 -h` Output
============================
96K     ./tmp
128K    ./home
23M     ./root
...
94M     ./etc
4.0K    ./.pulse
3.4G    .
```

Comment: Please include the output of the commands themselves. We need to see `du` and `df -h`. Also have a look at this Q&A: [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete (unlink) a file which is kept open by a process, you'll see the usage disappearing from `du`, but still in use by `df`. As soon as the last process closes the file (which happens latest when that process exits), the space used by the file will be deallocated and available in `df` as well.

Comment: This is a named server. Is there a possibility that named is taking up *all that* space? Uptime is...wow...743 days.

Comment: @WilliamCarterBaller is rebooting an option? If the problem is a hung file, rebooting should clear it out.

Comment: You can check for deleted files with "lsof -n | grep deleted". As a bonus you also see what process is keeping those files open. You can empty such files by doing "> /proc/$process_id/fd/$fd", $process_id is the 2nd column, $fd is the 5th column.

Comment: Wow @wurtel! You're totally right. Output of lsof -n | grep deleted gave: rsyslogd    943      root    1w      REG      253,0 20649662640     122793 /var/log/messages.20140731 (deleted). 20649662640b translates to 20.64G. Restarting rsyslog fixe the issue! Thank you!!

Comment: It is life-saving to know that you may not be able to free disk space by simply deleting large (and growing) files in an emergency disk full situation, you have to make sure that the process writing into that file also closes the file. If that's not an option, instead of deleting the file, you should choose to truncate its contents (`:> filename`).

Answer (score 0):

Linux keeps a buffer space, that can only be used by root. Running `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1` will show the number of reserved blocks in its output.

To turn off reserved blocks altogether just use the following command:

```
sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda1
```

Comment: tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/vg_dns-lv_root gives the following:  Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              1859584
Block count:              7427072
Reserved block count:     371353
Free blocks:              829324
Free inodes:              1736734
...

Comment: That means Reserved Block Count is 371353, or  0.177074909G total?

Answer (score 0):

@wurtel's information fixed it.

```
Output of `lsof -n | grep deleted`
================================== 
rsyslogd 943 root 1w REG 253,0 20649662640 122793 /var/log/messages.20140731 (deleted).
```

20649662640b translates to 20.64G. Restarting rsyslog fixe the issue!

Thank you everyone!!

Comment: kill -hup of the rsyslogd process would have fixed it as well, that tells rsyslogd to close and reopen its logfiles. Now go figure out why the logfile rotation was performed but not the signalling :-)